# What's the difference between the yml configuration file in serverless framework and SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, frameworks, aws-cloudformation, serverless, sam

It appears that SAM is implemented in the Serverelss framework; however, I am unable to find any documentation on this based on the lack of documentation from server less framework compared to AWS. AWS goes in to depth with SAM (as I am studying for the test) but I use serverless framework for my deployments and I'm trying to figure out the difference between the configuration file between the two.

Answer (score 1):

They are related but are not quite the same thing. SAM and Serverless Framework are both layers on top of CloudFormation (when deploying to AWS; Serverless works with other providers too). They abstract away some of the things that make defining serverless applications in CloudFormation hard, but code written for SAM won't work with Serverless Framework, and vice versa. SAM templates can also have CloudFormation templates embedded in them. In that regard they are an extension or a superset.

Another difference is that SAM provides some tools for running functions locally and debugging them.